# Possible ways to avoid BAD WRITES in MySql

Tags: mysql, transactions, isolation-level

Suppose we have one Transaction -

**Transaction T1**

```
S1=>   id1 = select id, colA, colB, colC from table A where colA = 'A1';

S2=>   update table A set colB = 'B1' where id = 'id1'
```

Above, I want to change `colB` to `B1`, only if `colA` value is `A1`

**Transaction T2**

```
 S3=>  update  table A set colA = 'A2' where colA = 'A1';
```

Above Transaction sets `colA` value to `A2`

So, in the above scenario, if  `S1` from `T1` happens, and then `S3` from `T2` happens, then `S2` from `T1`, then it will be wrong, as after execution of S3, value of colA is `A2`, so i don't want  S2 to be a success.

How can I avoid this?

**Possible solutions -**

1. Use Optimistic / Pessimistic locking : I will go for this, only if no other option works
2. Use SELECT for UPDATE: Like `update table A set colB = 'B1' where id = 'id1' and colA = 'A1'`
3. Use Transaction Isolation level `SERIALIZABLE`

Can I achieve what I want using 3? Which one will be better out of these 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to change colB to B1, only if colA value is A1*

Then make that part of the WHERE clause

```
update table A 
    set colB = 'B1' 
where id = 'id1'
AND colA = 'A1'
```

Comment: Yes, wanted to ask, can I make the transaction isolation level as `SERIALIZABLE` and also achieve it?